# Use async/await somehow before 1.6?

Tags: typescript

Want to switch to typescript for the type hinting, but don't want to give up async await (which can be used now via Babel).

Is there anything I can do besides wait?

Answer (score 3):

At this point in time the code is not completely stable. So you have to wait. At least a month more.

Comment: A few months later >>> If we target ES6, is it possible to use today? ie for code that will only run on the latest iojs.   Also saw this post which implies something was working  https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/typescript-1-5-async-functions/